# Illegal Argument Exception while registering for Blackberry Push service

Tags: blackberry, push

I am registering to Blackberry push by using below code but i am getting illegal argument exception.I did not understand the problem.Please tell me what is the problem if it not correct.Plese provide some resource to develop service.

```
Thread t=new Thread()
     {
         public void run()
         {

              ApplicationDescriptor ad = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
              byte serverType = PushApplicationDescriptor.SERVER_TYPE_BPAS;
              PushApplicationDescriptor pad = new PushApplicationDescriptor(appId,port,serverUrl,serverType,ad);
              PushApplicationStatus pushApplicationStatus = PushApplicationRegistry.getStatus(pad);
              byte pasStatus = pushApplicationStatus.getStatus();
              if (pasStatus != PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_ACTIVE
                        && pasStatus != PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_PENDING) {
                    PushApplicationRegistry.registerApplication(pad);
                    System.out.println("Registering new..." + pasStatus);
                    _imageField.setText("Registering new..." + pasStatus);
                } else {
                    _imageField.setText("Already registered device..."+pasStatus);
                    System.out.println("Already registered device..." + pasStatus);
                }
              lf.setText("Label"+pasStatus);

         }
     };
     t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you using device or simulator ?. there is no network coverage in simulator. so you cant register via simulator. also BIS is activated in device.

Comment: how can i know bis is activated or not in my device

Comment: BIS is blackberry internet service. it is internet service provided by blackberry.

Comment: boolean bisCoverage = CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient( CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B );